# goToNextSlid and goToPreviousSlide public method not working in bxslider plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, bxslider

I use the bxslider plugin in jquery.
 I set the controls as false and i set the new image for go to next slide and previous slide.

```
<a href="#" id="slider-previous"><img src='rightButton.jpg class="horSlideNext" /></a>
<a href="#" id="slider-next"><img src='leftButton.jpg' class="horSlidePrev" /></a>

var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'horizontal',
  controls:false
});
```

I use goToNextSlid and goToPreviousSlide public method

```
$('#slider-next').click(function(){
  slider.goToNextSlide();
  return false;
});
$('#slider-previous').click(function(){
  slider.goToPreviousSlide();
  return false;
});
```

But this public methods are not working

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade'
    });

    $('#slider-next').click(function () {
        slider.goToNextSlide();
        return false;
    });
    $('#slider-previous').click(function () {
        slider.goToPrevSlide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aau9pyw9/

Comment: Try this:
<a href="#" id="slider-previous">prev</a>
<a href="#" id="slider-next">next</a>
if it works fine then  you may have to add missed single quote in image tag: src='rightButton.jpg'

Comment: This is correct and it works. @GowthamV you have incorrectly called goToPreviousSlide in place of goToPrevSlide.